# vsperfmon not collecting any coverage data for asp.net mvc website

Tags: instrumentation, perfmon

I'm using vsperfmon to collect code coverage inforation for an asp.net mvc website. My ultimate goal is to collect code coverage data while I'm running browser automation tests against the website. Here is what I'm doing right now

1. Use vsinstr.exe to instrument the DLL of the asp.net mvc website
   vsinstr.exe /coverage
2. Start perfmon in coverage mode
   vsperfmon /start:coverage /output:c:\result.coverage /user:

   Here for username I have tried "Network Service", "Everyone" and the user configured for the app pool of my website. I have also tried cross session option.
3. Browse the website for few minutes
4. Shutdown the perfmon

   vsperfcmd /shutdown

   I have also tried shutting down iis before running step 4

After this, when I look at results.coverage in visual studio, it says coverage file is empty.

I'm following this video - http://www.asp.net/visual-studio-team-system/videos/how-do-i-enable-code-coverage-and-profiling-in-production-applications

Am I missing something here